# Entry_date is the season

Tags: entry-date

Is it possible to show the entry_date to the season it's been published? e.g. Written in Autumn at.........

This will also need to work in different time zones. Client will publish from Europe and Australia.

Comment: I believe is better for you to **show** the season, instead of save the season. How do you will order entries, for example?

Comment: Hi Robson, I'll edit the original query to be more precise...

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditionals and the date format function to extract the month from the date and output a different season.

Of course you would then need to define seasons by the start/end of months. It's down to how precise you wish to be.

For instance;

```
{if "{entry_date format='%n'}" > 1 AND "{entry_date format='%n'}" < 5}
    It's Spring(ish) (matches feb, mar, apr)
{/if}
```

Thinking about this further you could be extremely precise if you forgo the automation and simply note the dates of the season changes for the next few years. How long do you expect this incarnation of the site to be live? It strikes me that it would be easier to hardcode the dates than write code to calculate them.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

I believe your better solution is to code a simple plugin which converts a date into a season and vice-verse. You can provide as parameters:

- `season`;
- `start` or `end`;
- `hemisphere`;

Or something like that and use the returned value to fill the parameters [`start_on`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on) and [´stop_before`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#stop-before).

Comment: Wish I could, Robson. I assumed there's a swiss army knife add-on in the #eecms community which can be tinkered to do this.

Comment: @Nutmeg, this is a very, very, very specific need. I never  even thought about something like this.

---

Why can't you code this by yourself? Apart from the impossible precision, due to the season change every year, this plugin can be done easily.

Comment: How would you define the start/end of seasons normally (i.e. not in code)?

Comment: @foamcow, are you asking me or him?

Comment: I was asking the original poster. But anyone could answer :)